# Enumerating through objects in `ContentPresenter`

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls

Windows Phone 8.1

I have a custom control with `ContentPresenter`.

When this control is used in `XAML` page, it is possible to add any type of `FrameworkElement` there.

I want to enumerate through all items in `ContentPresenter` and act accordingly to what I find there.

This is my approach:

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        validationContentPresenter = this.GetTemplateChild("ValidationContentPresenter") as ContentPresenter;
        //it does not compile since `Content` does not seem to allow it
        foreach (FrameworkElement o in validationContentPresenter.Content)
        {

        }
}
```

As you can see I find my `ContentPresenter` but do not know how to iterate through the list of items there.

Any help?

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on what you find in the `Content` property. It can literally be set to anything (though not all objects will be presentable).

If it returns something like an instance of `string`, then you're done. Nothing to iterate.

If it returns e.g. `FrameworkElement`, or any `DependencyObject` type for that matter (though not all necessarily would have children), then you can enumerate the object graph for that object using the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) class. Since it's a tree structure, you'd have to do that recursively. For example:

```
IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetAllVisualChildren(DependencyObject o)
{
    yield return o;

    int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(o);

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        foreach (DependencyObject child in
            GetAllVisualChildren(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(i)))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

You could use that like this:

```
DependencyObject dobj = validationContentPresenter.Content as DependencyObject;

if (dobj != null)
{
    foreach (FrameworkElement o in
        GetAllVisualChildren(dobj).OfType<FrameworkElement>())
    {

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, your question is a bit vague on what exactly you expect to assign to the `Content` property, so I can't really say for sure what the best approach for you is. But hopefully the above gives you some ideas. If it doesn't answer your question completely, please edit your question to provide more specific details, including [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your specific scenario.

Comment: Items in `validationContentPresenter` will be one or more custom controls.

Comment: @JacekWojcik: well, you can only assign one object to the `Content` property. So the real question is what is it that you're assigning to that. But assuming it's an actual `FrameworkElement` (e.g. a custom control itself), then the above should work fine.